# Could not determine artifacts for org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:

Tags: spring-boot, build.gradle

I'm getting some errors :

> Could not resolve all dependencies ...

```
   > Could not determine artifacts for org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:1.2.1.RELEASE
      > Could not get resource 'https://repo.spring.io/plugins-release/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/1.2.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-parent-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar'.
         > Could not HEAD 'https://repo.spring.io/plugins-release/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/1.2.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-parent-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar'. Received status code 401 from server: Unauthorized
```

It requires username and password (I typed the url in the browser)

**Update:**

> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':gisett-backend:classpath'.
> Could not find io.spring.gradle:propdeps-plugin:0.0.9.RELEASE.
> Searched in the following locations:
> - https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/spring/gradle/propdeps-plugin/0.0.9.RELEASE/propdeps-plugin-0.0.9.RELEASE.pom
> - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/io/spring/gradle/propdeps-plugin/0.0.9.RELEASE/propdeps-plugin-0.0.9.RELEASE.pom
> - https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/io/spring/gradle/propdeps-plugin/0.0.9.RELEASE/propdeps-plugin-0.0.9.RELEASE.pom
> How can I fix it? Thanks

Comment: You should use maven central not the spring.io repositories (this has been announced in oktober last year already!). See https://spring.io/blog/2020/10/29/notice-of-permissions-changes-to-repo-spring-io-fall-and-winter-2020

Comment: Ok, but now there is another error

Comment: Please read the linked blog post. Also you are using quite an old Spring Boot versions, you might want to consider to update.

Comment: I read the blog. It does not help - I put  springBootVersion = '2.2.9.RELEASE' and I get 'Could not find io.spring.gradle:propdeps-plugin:0.0.9.RELEASE.'...

Comment: Without seeing your `build.gradle` this question is simply impossible to answer.

Comment: Here: https://github.com/EstherSD/gis/blob/main/build.gradle